# Unexplained 5-second latency with Retrofit/OkHttp

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

My Android app makes numerous concurrent requests to various API endpoints, and generally I observe latencies on the order of 200ms, which I would expect. (I'm using the latest Retrofit 2 and OkHttp 3, with all default configuration)

However, for certain specific requests the latency suddenly jumps to ~5200 ms. I'm very certain that this latency isn't on the server side, since I can query the endpoint in a browser and get normal latency, and both the browser and my device are on the same wifi connection.

There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to it: it's only certain requests that are affected (consistently), and it also seems to be device-specific -- it's happening on two of my real devices, but doesn't happen in the emulator.

But it does seem suspicious that the bad latency is precisely 5 seconds greater than normal, which suggests that something on the client side is deliberately blocking the request for 5 seconds.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this delay?

Comment: We are also observing this on an Android app, Retrofit 2.3.0 and OkHTTP 3.10.0. Server analytics indicate normal response times (200-500ms) but some requests from the app have high latencies like yours. Have you identified any potencial cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a server-side issue, after all.  Or rather, it was an issue where the app was not properly handling the cookies that the server was providing, and was passing back cookies that were expired, causing the server to wait 5 seconds before responding.